# Strange number of upvotes for questions

Tags: support, reputation, moderation, gaming-the-system

Can someone look into [neurofluxations](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285178/) recent jQuery questions. It appears there is some gaming going on as the amount of upvotes he has been receiving is way out of kilter with a standard jQuery question.

Comment: sorting on votes shows that 9 upvotes is the maximum ammount of upvotes neurofluxations received. I don't follow jQuery questions but that doesn't strike me as strange.

Comment: Well, take a look at the recent jQuery questions. You will struggle to find any with 5+ upvotes, especially in the timeframe that he received them. The last q got 8 upvotes within 4 mins.

Comment: ah I see. From a comment of Will: *he's part of the dch.co.uk vote ring. Its been noted, and their fate is awaiting decision by the dark lords of SO. We are hoping they will realize its douchy to automatically upvote your friends and/or colleagues and stop doing it.*

Comment: For reference, here's a data dump query of posts on the jquery tag along with the number of upvotes (I ignored downvotes for simplicity): http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/7413/recent-posts-in-a-given-tag-along-with-the-upvotes-on-them?TagName=jquery

Comment: IMHO this should be treated as a "serial upvoting" case, only manually noted in the DB rather than via the detection script -- i.e. all the members of this "vote ring" should be permanently prevented from voting on each others' posts, and all such previous votes nullified in the DB. Let their posts stand or fall on their merits, from votes from the rest of the SO community.

Comment: It surprises me time and again how naïve I seem to be. Gaming the system like that wouldn't even have crossed my mind...

Answer (score 3):

What's really off-kilter is that 3 out of the 4 questions have way more upvotes for the questions than for the answers.